# How to derive $\prod x: \text{Nat}, Id(S(x), O) \to \bot$ in Intensional Type Theory

Tags: logic, proof-theory, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

In HoTT Lecture, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWmXF-P4-Z8&list=PL1-2D_rCQBarjdqnM21sOsx09CtFSVO6Z&index=7, Harper introduced a dependent form of recursion rule:

$$
\Gamma \vdash M : Nat ~~~ \Gamma,z: Nat \vdash C ~\text{type} ~~~ \Gamma \vdash N : [O/z] C ~~~ \Gamma, x : Nat, y : [x/z] C \vdash P : [S(x)/z] C\over \Gamma \vdash \text{rec}[z.C](M, N, xy.P) : [M/z]C
$$

and beta rules:
$$
\text{rec}[z.C](O, N, x,y. P) \equiv N \\
\text{rec}[z.C](S(M), N, x,y. P) \equiv [M, rec[z.C](M, N, x, y . P) / x, y]P \\
$$
And then an exercise was left as the following:
$$
\prod x: Nat. (\text{Id}_{Nat}(S(x), O) \to \bot)
$$

To proof this, I want to construct something like:
$$
\lambda x : \text{Nat} ~ \lambda m : \text{Id(S(x), O)}~ \text{rec}[...](...) : \bot
$$

But I have no idea how could I construct such recursion rule to lead to a bottom type.
Moreover, it seems to me that if my motive is bottom, then the rule implies that I need to first have some N that is of bottom type. But there is not any instance that is of bottom type, so how come I can construct such recursion rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you the informal answer.

First, construct a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to Type$ defined by $\DeclareMathOperator{Id}{Id}$

$$f(0) = \bot$$
$$f(S(n)) = \top$$

Then, prove $\prod n, m : \mathbb{N}, (\Id_\mathbb{N}(n, m) \to f(n) \to f(m))$ using path induction.

Then if we have $\Id(S(x), 0)$, then we have $f(S(x)) \to f(0)$. That is, we have $\top \to \bot$.

Now $\top$ is a true proposition, so we can conclude $\bot$. Or in other words, there is some element $* : \top$, so therefore we can use our function $\top \to \bot$ to get an element of $\bot$.

In order to give you a formal answer, you would need to include your rule for path induction.

Edit: let's proceed with a slightly more formal proof.

To define $f : \mathbb{N} \to Type$, we define

$$f :\equiv \lambda n . rec[z.Type](n, \bot, xy. \top)$$

Then, we define $g : \prod n, m : \mathbb{N}, (\Id_\mathbb{N}(n, m) \to f(n) \to f(m))$ by

$$g :\equiv \lambda n . \lambda m . \lambda p . J[n, m, z . f(n) \to f(m)](p; x . \lambda y . y)$$

Now, we define $h : \prod x : \mathbb{N}, \Id(S(x), 0) \to \bot$ by

$$h :\equiv \lambda x . \lambda p . g(S(x), 0, p)(*)$$

To proceed with maximum formality and with no intermediate definitions at all, we have

$$\lambda x . \lambda p . (\lambda n . \lambda m . \lambda . p . J[n, m, z . (\lambda n . rec[z.Type](n, \bot, xy. \top))(n) \to (\lambda n . rec[z.Type](n, \bot, xy. \top))(m)](p; x . \lambda y . y)) ((S(x), 0, p)(*) : \prod x : \mathbb{N}, \Id(S(x), 0) \to \bot$$

Comment: The path induction principle gives as:
$$
{\Gamma \vdash P : \text{Id}_A(M, N) ~~~ \Gamma , x: A, y: A, z: \text{Id}(x, y) \vdash C ~\text{type}~~~ \Gamma, x:A \vdash Q : [x, x, \text{refl}_A(x)/x, y, z] C} \over {
\Gamma \vdash J[x, y, z.C](P; x.Q): [M, N, P / x, y, z] C
}
$$
And the beta rule is
$$
J[x, y, z.C](\text{refl}_A(M), x.Q) = [M/x]Q : [M, M, \text{refl}_A(M)/x, y, z]C
$$
But strangely, it was in a lecture after the exercise.

Comment: @ShrodingerZHU Do you mean you're not allowed to use that? But the theorem you want to prove is impossible to prove without J and large elimination.

Comment: @Mark Saving Thanks so much! Yeah, at the time I was given this exercise in the video, I was not aware of J rules yet; so I think maybe Harper intended to make this an inspring example? But I think I could understand the proof with the J rule now with your help. Thanks again!

Comment: @SchrodingerZHU You're welcome.